# Multiple EC2 instances connecting to single SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

We are using cloudformation template to create multiple EC2 instances. We have Auto scaling and ELB defined. Each EC2 instance runs with its own Tomcat server and a web application. We connect to SQS to pull messages and write to RDS database from this web app.

Problem statement - We do not want both EC2 instances pulling the same message from SQS and writing to RDS. Could you please direct me on how to make this process efficient?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a good practice to achieve the "Exactly-once delivery" behavior with Amazon SQS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484845/what-is-a-good-practice-to-achieve-the-exactly-once-delivery-behavior-with-ama)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is reasonable, check out an explanation below.

Immediately after the component receives the message, the message is still in the queue. In order to prevent a situation you described, Amazon SQS blocks them with a visibility timeout, which is a period of time during which Amazon SQS prevents other consuming components from receiving and processing that message. Once your instance processed a message it should invoke a command that deletes a message from the queue. If for some reason, instance didn't finish a job during visibility timeout, the message becomes available for other instances again.

You can find more information here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/AboutVT.html

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. This is clear to me now.