# .Net Core - AWS DynamoDb With Retry Policies

Tags: c#, .net-core, amazon-dynamodb, polly, retry-logic

I want to use retry pattern with Aws DynamoDb. I don't know if i can use the `Polly` package from nuget. I researched a lot, but i learnt how to implement Polly but i couldn't find how to connect Polly with DynamoDb.

Is there any way to using Polly retry policies with Aws DynamoDb?

I'll give you an example code block and i want to know how to implement this with DynamoDb

```
Policy
  .WaitAndRetryAsync(
    5, 
    retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)), 
    (exception, timeSpan, context) => {
      // do something
    }
  );
```

I am new with Aws Services, can you give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the .NET SDK for DynamoDb then you can do the following:

### The to-be-decorated method

Lets suppose you have simple point query like this:

```
public int GetAlternativeKey(int hashKey, string rangeKey)
{
  var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
  var table = Table.LoadTable(client, "LookupTable");
  var item = table.GetItem(hashKey, rangeKey);
  return (int)item["Id"];
}
```

### The retry policy

Trigger retry in case of [throttling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html#Programming.Errors.RetryAndBackoff)

```
var retry policy = Policy
  .Handle<ThrottlingException>()
  .Or<ProvisionedThroughputExceededException>()
  .WaitAndRetry(5, 
    retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt))
  );
```

#### Note

Please remember to use retry policy against idempotent operations

### Decorate the method with the policy

If you have defined your to-be-decorated method (and the policy as well) as synchronous

```
policy.Execute(() => GetAlternativeKey(hk, rk));
```

If you have defined them as async

```
await policy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await GetAlternativeKey(hk, rk));
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

> If I understood right, these are only errors I can have which you shared.

No, that's not true. These were just examples. Most of the exceptions that can be thrown by this library is inherited from the [`AmazonDynamoDBException`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_DynamoDBv2_AmazonDynamoDBException.htm). Please see **Inheritance Hierarchy** section to get the full list of derived exceptions.

> You talked about only use it against idempotent operations. Here what do you mean by idempotent operations? Are you suggesting me to only use retry policies with GET operations and not to use them in POST?

Idempotent operations do not cause any unwanted behaviour in case of re-execution (like duplicated inserts, multiple increment on a counter, etc.) In case of insert you can do a [conditional check for not existence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106784/how-to-insert-to-dynamodb-just-if-the-key-does-not-exist) as a part of your putItem request. Please also check the **Idempotency** section of the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html#transaction-apis-txwriteitems).

Comment: If i understood right, these are only errors i can have which you shared. If i design my policy according to these errors and i can use my policy over `ExecuteAsync` method. I am okay in this part now, thank you very much. And you talked about only use it against idempotent operations. Here what do you mean by idempotent operations? Are you suggesting me to only use retry policies with GET operations and not to use them in POST? Actually i just need to retry a couple times if i cannot get/set the data from DynamoDb due to momentary network issues. I believe this way will be more resilient.

Comment: @jack I've updated my post to provide answer for your questions. Please revisit it

Comment: why the exponential increase in wait, rather than a fixed (say) 15 seconds?

Comment: `GetAlternativeKey(hk, rk)` returns an int. How do you capture that via the `policy.Execute` ?

Comment: @Kappacake *why the exponential increase in wait, rather than a fixed (say) 15 seconds?* I've used the same `sleepDurationProvider` as the OP. If you are asking why should we use exponential backoff then I would suggest to read [this project's readme](https://github.com/Polly-Contrib/Polly.Contrib.WaitAndRetry).

Comment: @Kappacake *GetAlternativeKey(hk, rk) returns an int. How do you capture that via the policy.Execute?* You need to adjust the definition of the policy from `Policy.Handle<...` to `Policy<int>.Handle<...`. After this adjustment the `Execute` will return an int or throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I actually went for `ExecuteAndCapture` which returns whatever value the inner function returns. Regarding the exponential increase in wait, still not sure if that is the best strategy in my scenario, which is similar to the OP but I'm getting the Rate Exceeded error from AWS CloudFormation, EC2 and other SDKs bits. However, AWS itself recommends an exponential increase in wait, so I'll stick with this unless I find any problems. ([Link to the relevant AWS doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-rate-exceeded-error/))